# Vaultwarden in kubernetes with multiple path

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am trying to get vaultwarden to work with nextcloud on the same ingress controller. I'd be very very very appreciated to anybody who can help me here.

So, this is my manifest.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vaultwarden-cm
  namespace: nc
data:
  DOMAIN: 'httрs://mysite.com/vwrd'
  DATA_FOLDER: '/data'
  WEB_VAULT_ENABLED: 'true'
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vaultwarden
  namespace: nc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vaultwarden
  template:
    metadata:
      name: vaultwarden
      labels:
        app: vaultwarden
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: vaultwarden/server:latest
          name: vaultwarden
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: vaultwarden-cm
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vw-nodeport
  namespace: nc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31111
  selector:
    app: vaultwarden
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mysite
  namespace: nc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Request-Id: $req_id";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header: "keep-alive"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 512m
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-production"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - mysite.com
      secretName: mysite.tls
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nc-nodeport
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /vwrd
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: vw-nodeport
            port:
              number: 80
```

In this case, nextcloud works (by addressing nc-nodeport service) with mysite.ru, but vaultwarden doesnt! In logs of nginx I see addressing to vw-nodeport but it gives 404 response.  It looks like VW responses like mysite.com/app instead of mysite.com/vwrd/app

If I set vaultwarden to root path - VW works fine.  But this not what I need.

```
- path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: vw-nodeport
            port:
              number: 80
```

So, please, give me a clue what is wrong with my config?

Thanks in advance